# SwiftUI Navigation With Slide-Out Menu

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI App and I am having trouble getting navigation to work properly. Anything that comes close to working just feels hacked together. I have a slide-out menu I made by following [this tutorial.](https://www.blckbirds.com/post/side-menu-hamburger-menu-in-swiftui) [The slide-out menu looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnAH1.png) I also have multiple views that I would like to show when an item from the slide-out menu is selected. [I want it to appear like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8X2t.png) I have a class for the menu as shown below.

```swift
enum menuItems {
    case Subview1
    case Subview2
    case Subview3
    case Subview4
    case Subview5
}

class SideMenu: ObservableObject {
    @Published var show: Bool = false
    @Published var selection: menuItems = menuItems.Events
}
```

Then my ContentView is shown below

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var menu: SideMenu
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            MainView()
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                .offset(x: self.menu.show ? geometry.size.width/2 : 0)
            .disabled(self.menu.show ? true : false)
            if self.menu.show {
                MenuView()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/2)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var menu: SideMenu
    var featureDetailView: some View {

        switch menu.selection {
        case menuItems.Subview1:
            return AnyView(Subview1())
        case menuItems.Subview2:
            return AnyView(Subview2())
        case menuItems.Subview3:
            return AnyView(Subview3())
        case menuItems.Subview4:
            return AnyView(Subview4())
        case menuItems.Subview5:
            return AnyView(Subview5())
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            featureDetailView
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Subview 1 Title"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading: (
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.menu.show.toggle()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                ))
                .background(NavigationConfigurator { nc in
                    nc.navigationBar.barTintColor = .systemBlue
                    nc.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
                })
            }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

So ContentView is responsible for either showing the MainView or the slide-out menu. Then MainView will show the correct subview based on the value of `menu.selection`. All of this works but handling the navigation is messy and I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this? I was also having trouble changing navigationBarTitle when a different Subview is shown.